# Method not applicable for arguments with generics

Tags: java, generics

I am no expert with generics and as I am trying to do a reengineering of some classes to avoid code repetition, I am forcing myself to use generics in order to do it the best way possible.

I am getting the next error in the lines I marked:

> The method delete(Long) in the type CrudRepository is not applicable for the arguments (capture#5-of ? extends KeyProfileEntity)

Here my class:

```
public abstract class KeyProfileService {

    protected CrudRepository<? extends KeyProfileEntity, Long> myRepository;

    public List<KeyProfileEntity> getList() {
        List<KeyProfileEntity> result = new ArrayList<>();
        this.myRepository.findAll().forEach(result::add);
        return result;
    }

    public KeyProfileEntity create(KeyProfileEntity entity) {
        return this.myRepository.save(entity);                      //error
    }

    public boolean delete(long id) {
        if (this.myRepository.exists(id)) {
            this.myRepository.delete(this.myRepository.findOne(id));//error
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void update(KeyProfileEntity entity) {
        this.myRepository.save(entity);                             //error
    }

    public KeyProfileEntity getEmployee(long id) throws NotFoundEntryException {
        if (this.myRepository.exists(id))
            return this.myRepository.findOne(id);
        throw new NotFoundEntryException();
    }

}
```

I think this is all the info you guys need, otherwise comment and I will attach more.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The issue is in CrudRepository

Comment: Hi Maurice. Could you give me more info? Do you mean in its declaration? I tried before just
protected CrudRepository <KeyProfileEntity, Long> myRepository; but the thing is that I need to specify the "? extends" to make it assignable from another method. Thanks for your help!

Comment: this is not the issue: the issue is that the delete method expects a Long

Comment: I changed long to Long but still same error: "The method delete(Long) in the type CrudRepository<capture#4-of ? extends KeyProfileEntity,Long> is not applicable for the arguments (capture#5-of ? extends KeyProfileEntity)"

Comment: I'm talking about the delete method in CrudRepository

Comment: Sorry I got it :P my mind tricked me, thanks!

Comment: what about save? I have no clue there...

Comment: what about it ?

Comment: When I call crudRepository.save(entity) it throws the error mentioned above. I cannot figure out what can be...

Comment: See @Tamas 's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it by removing the `<? extends ...>` bound wildcard from `myRepository`:

```
protected CrudRepository<KeyProfileEntity, Long> myRepository;
```

As far as I can see, your class will be still usable, even with subclasses of `KeyProfileEntity`:

```
    KeyProfileService service = new KeyProfileServiceImpl();
    service.update(new ChildKeyProfileEntity());
```

There will be only one limitation: `getList()` will always return a `List<KeyProfileEntity>`, not a `List<ChildKeyProfileEntity>`.

Alternatively, you can make the `KeyProfileService` generic and make sure you use a bound, **known** subtype:

```
public abstract class KeyProfileService<K extends KeyProfileEntity> {

    protected CrudRepository<K, Long> myRepository;

    public List<K> getList() { // using K
        List<K> result = new ArrayList<>(); // here too
        this.myRepository.findAll().forEach(result::add);
        return result;
    }

    public K create(K entity) { // using K
        return this.myRepository.save(entity);
    }
...
}
```